# Implementing "tab completion" in RichEdit Winapi

Tags: c, winapi

This is a feature you see in a lot of IRC clients. Basically, if you type a string "Ad" and then hit tab the client will fill in the first matching nick (in the case of an IRC client) mathcing 'Ad' - so let's say it fills in Adam. But, like bash, if you keep hitting tab it should cycle through all the names containing "Ad" as a prefix.

I'm not quite sure how to implement this in the Wndproc for a RichEdit though. Specifically, when a user hits tab I need to get the current 'token', save it, and get all the prefixes and fill in the first. If he hits tab again I need to get the next prefix, and so on, but I need to empty the prefix list once I get a WM_CHAR that's *not* tab -- I think?

I'm wondering if there's some easier, less hacky way though, or if anybody has seen code that does this?

Thanks.

Comment: RichEdit does not natively support what you are asking for, so you must implement it manually.  While handling key presses, you can use [`EM_FINDWORDBREAK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788018.aspx), [`EM_EXSETSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788007.aspx) and [`EM_GETSELTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774190.aspx) to find and extract tokens, and [`EM_REPLACESEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633.aspx) to replace them.

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand how I'd use EM_FINDWORDBREAK. I'm guessing for EXSETSEL, etc. I'd highlight either the current token or the "inserted suffix" to know what I'm up to?

Comment: On the 1st Tab, use `EM_EXGETSEL` to get the caret index, then `EM_FINDWORDBREAK` to find the start and end indexes of the word at the caret, then `EM_GETTEXTRANGE` to read the word. Search for tokens with that word as prefix, then use `EM_EXSETSEL` and `EM_REPLACESEL` to select+replace the word with the first token found. Remember the start index and length of that inserted token, so that on the next Tab, you can use `EM_EXSETSEL` and `EM_REPLACESEL` to select+replace it with the next token. Repeat as needed until a non-Tab is pressed. It is not that hard. I tested it and it works fairly well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful though Remy's comments are, it seems to me that this question is more about what the *logic* should be to implement kind-of-bash-style auto-completion than anything else.  On that basis, and based on what you posted, which I found slightly confusing, I think it should be something like this (pseudo-code);

```
int autocomplete_index = 0;
string autocomplete_prefix;

on_tab:
    if (autocomplete_prefix == "")
    {
        autocomplete_prefix = current_contents_of_edit_field ();
        autocomplete_index = 0;
    }

    auto autocomplete_result = get_autocomplete_string (autocomplete_prefix, autocomplete_index++);
    if (autocomplete_result != "")
        replace_contents_of_edit_field_and_move_caret_to_end (autocomplete_result);
    else
        beep ();  // or cycle round
    done;

on_any_other_char:
    autocomplete_prefix = "";
```

If the rich edit control is embedded in a dialog, you also need to ensure that the dialog manager does not speak in and snaffle `VK_TAB` before you do.  That normally doesn't happen for rich edit controls (although it does for regular edit controls - go figure) but if it does you can handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` appropriately in your WndProc (details on request).

And 'hacky'?  Why?  I don't think so.  Sounds like a good idea to me.